# Show that a function is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

I know how to find if a function is differentiable at a point like when $x=0$, but how do you find if a function is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$?

For example, 
  $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^3\sin(1/x^2),  & x\neq0 \\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}$$
or even for $f(x)=|x|^3$.

Comment: Apply the definition of the derivative.

Comment: In both cases $f$ is clearly differentiable in $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$, so you only need to check differentiability at $0$.

Comment: @Andrea: How do I mathematically show that it is differentiable from (−∞,0) and (0, ∞)? I know how to check it at 0.

Comment: If $x \neq 0$, $f(x)$  is a composition and product of differentiable functions, so it is differentiable by the chain and product rules.

Comment: Because there $f$ is obtained by multiplying and composing elementary functions (powers and the sine), which are differentiable everywhere.

Comment: @Charlie So I just find the derivative of the function? Do I need to worry about if x is less than 0 or greater than 0?

Comment: No, as @Andrea says, the only "problem" point is when $x = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way would be something along the lines of expressing your function on a reasonably large open set $U$ as a combination of elementary functions. For this functions you know that they will be differentiable everywhere on $U$ for example you could just write down the derivative. Then just check the "rest"  $\mathbb{R}\setminus U$ manually. So for example your function $\vert x\vert^3$ could be written as 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^3,  & x\geq0 \\
-x^3, & x<0.
\end{cases}$$

So you allready now that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ because you can write down the derivative. Now check for $x=0$.